# Efficient ways to represent a (possibly big) graph with unknown structure using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, graph

My setup is basically the following:

- I have a set of nodes (represented as integer numbers `0, ...`). Possibly several millions of them.
- These nodes are connected in an undirected graph without weights.
- The structure of the graph is unknown, both sparse and dense graphs are possible, although dense graphs with several million nodes are unlikely.
- I would like to use numpy as much as possible to ensure compatibility with other parts of the project. I hope that I can implement all operations on the graph as numpy ufuncs.

The problem is: when operating on the graph, searching for edges and creating and removing edges will happen often. My idea is to use a sorted adjacency list, however I am not quite sure how to implement efficiently it using numpy arrays.

Is there an efficient way to implement it using only numpy arrays or will I have to use some other data structure instead?

Comment: Have you thought about using a library? Maybe at least look at [`graph-tool`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/). It's aimed right at you, by the sounds.

Comment: I would suggest [`scipy.sparse.csgraph`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html) which is based on sparse `csr` matrices implemented on top of numpy arrays. But `csr` as well as numpy in general are not good for frequent inserting or deleting of elements.

Comment: @kwinkunks I will run some performance tests with `graph-tool`. However I do basically no graph analysis, most of the computations is update the nodes and edges and then converting the graph to a (non-graph) representation. This is why I hoped I could avoid a huge library.

Comment: The other thing to check out is specialized graph databases like [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com). Those might be faster for frequent insertion/deletion, support caching etc, and will be much easier on memory.

Comment: @kwinkunks As the package I am working on is being distributed over PyPI, bith graph-tool and Neo4j seem to be quite hard to use, considering how much effort it is to install them; in particular considering they are not on PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `numpy.ndarray` seems to be unfeasible for your specifications since you describe 1,000,000+ nodes, i.e. the corresponding matrix would have 1e12+ entries.

Instead you can use one of the [`scipy.sparse` matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) which allocate data as needed. In the overview they describe the pros and cons of the different implementations. For your application, which seems to involve creating and removing edges frequently, the [dictionary of keys](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html) implementation seems a good choice:

> This is an efficient structure for constructing sparse matrices incrementally.

The [linked list sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix) can be another option, but performance can be worse, if insertion happens at random.

Operations on these matrices are mostly similar to Numpy, but the usage of `numpy` functions is discouraged, as explained in the docs:

> Despite their similarity to NumPy arrays, it is strongly discouraged to use NumPy functions directly on these matrices because NumPy may not properly convert them for computations, leading to unexpected (and incorrect) results.

So you'd need to check the `scipy` library for an equivalent function. There are plenty available for performing graph operations on sparse matrices, in the [`scipy.sparse.csgraph`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html) module.

By the way [the `networkx` package](https://pypi.org/project/networkx/) is also a popular choice for working with graphs.

Comment: I will run some performance tests with those `scipy.sparse` matrices. They look quite promising.

Comment: Allright. I have tested it and it seems like both DOK sparse matrices and networkx graphs seem to be way too slow. Just creating a graph takes several seconds (up to several minutes).

Comment: @LittleByBlue Graph creation by DOK should be the fastest option since that's basically inserting into a `dict`. The final numbers depend on your specific use case, of course, so without any more information it's hard to judge. Could you update your question by including the snippet that you are interested in improving?

Comment: Ah. I made a mistake while using `timeit`. I will update the question once that is fixed.